# Trouble showing list of users and customers in view model?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a web app on MEAN stack and for some reason i have to save two different schema in same collection named  `"users"` and saved the `userSchema` and `customerSchema` in that collection in mongoose but in view model while listing the data in `user` list it shows `users` as well as customers which is saved in the collection. I want to display users list in and customers list in separate pages.

Can anyone guide me for this problem ??
Thank you in advance!

Comment: use ng-if to filter out both inside ng-repeat

Comment: can you give an example @RohitKumar how to deal with this please

Comment: Please give sample data and how it should be displayed : so that the code could follow

Comment: @RohitKumar i found the solution.Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options: you can either separate the server side queries and have two API calls, or you can use an angular filter (ng-filter) to display only one type in your table. If you're primarily going to be displaying only one type of user per page, I would suggest separating on the server side, to reduce the data transferred to the client, and to allow for improved security (for example if details of one type of user should not be publicly visible)